# Electron app won't install if name is different than product name

Tags: ubuntu, debian, electron, deb, electron-forge

I am using `electron-forge` to create my electron app and create distributables for My project.However I encountered a strange error.
My `name` field in `package.json` id `status-client` and so is my `productName` field.

With these values when I run electron-forge make I get my executable and then I can install it like a charm and find my app in the `Utilities` section in Ubuntu.

However the problem comes when I change the `productName` field in my `package.json` file.The executable will be created I am able to install it but the If I search my app with its new name I cannot find it anywhere.

Here is my new `package.json`:

{

```
    "name": "status-client",
    "productName": "Foo",
    "version": "1.0.4",
    "description": "Monitor when your raspberry pi goes online and when offline with desktop notifications",
    "main": "src/index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "electron-forge start",
        "package": "electron-forge package",
        "make": "electron-forge make",
        "lint": "eslint src"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "Manos Kounelakis <pkounelios@gmail.com>",
    "license": "MIT",
    "config": {
        "forge": {
            "make_targets": {
                "win32": [
                    "squirrel"
                ],
                "darwin": [
                    "zip"
                ],
                "linux": [
                    "deb"
                ]
            },
            "electronPackagerConfig": {
                "packageManager": "npm"
            },
            "electronWinstallerConfig": {
                "name": "status_client"
            },
            "electronInstallerDebian": {},
            "electronInstallerRedhat": {},
            "github_repository": {
                "owner": "",
                "name": ""
            },
            "windowsStoreConfig": {
                "packageName": "",
                "name": "statusclient"
            }
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "electron-compile": "^6.4.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "electron-prebuilt-compile": "1.7.5",
        "eslint": "^3.19.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.2.0"
    }
}
```

With the above package.json I get the executable and I install it but if I search my programs for `Foo` I get nothing.

Here is the original `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "status-client",
    "productName": "status-client",
    "version": "1.0.4",
    "description": "Monitor when your raspberry pi goes online and when offline with desktop notifications",
    "main": "src/index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "electron-forge start",
        "package": "electron-forge package",
        "make": "electron-forge make",
        "lint": "eslint src"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "Manos Kounelakis <pkounelios@gmail.com>",
    "license": "MIT",
    "config": {
        "forge": {
            "make_targets": {
                "win32": [
                    "squirrel"
                ],
                "darwin": [
                    "zip"
                ],
                "linux": [
                    "deb"
                ]
            },
            "electronPackagerConfig": {
                "packageManager": "npm"
            },
            "electronWinstallerConfig": {
                "name": "status_client"
            },
            "electronInstallerDebian": {},
            "electronInstallerRedhat": {},
            "github_repository": {
                "owner": "",
                "name": ""
            },
            "windowsStoreConfig": {
                "packageName": "",
                "name": "statusclient"
            }
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "electron-compile": "^6.4.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "electron-prebuilt-compile": "1.7.5",
        "eslint": "^3.19.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.2.0"
    }
}
```

Now with the last package.json I get my executable .I can install it and when I search my programs for `status-client` I will find it.

I don't get any errors while running `electron-forge make`
Any Ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

That's because `/usr/bin/<name>` is a symbolic link to `/usr/lib/<name>/<name>` but the executable is at `/usr/lib/<name>/<productName>`.

It is done here:
https://github.com/unindented/electron-installer-debian/blob/master/src/installer.js#L232

`options.bin` is set to pkg.name at:
https://github.com/unindented/electron-installer-debian/blob/master/src/installer.js#L12

We can correct that symbolic link by setting the `bin` property of `electronInstallerDebian`:

```
{
    "name": "application-name",
    "productName": "Application Name",
    ...
    "config": {
        "forge": {
            ...
            "electronInstallerDebian": {
                "bin": "Application Name"
            }
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One Problem I can see is :

```
   {
     "name": "application-name",
```

replace "-" with "_"

```
"name": "application_name",
```

and try again.